# Bot.SendDocumentAsync(tgId, streamFile, "file sended!", false); throw exception Additional information: Error while copying content to a stream

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

i have created a async method , that its task is to send file to telegram server (then telegram bot can send the file to user) on user request  , its working fine when user are limited but when number of concurrent user increased , project crash , and throw exception

> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Error while copying content to a stream.

i have tried to not use "using" and dispose it but it didnt run and throw the same error instantaneously ,

my question is my method correct and its just telegram bug ? if so would creating a queue or a hashmap of sended file will help me ?

```
public static async void sendFileToUser(long tgId, int fileId)
    {
    ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException = null;
    String occuredException = "";
    try
    {
    string pathPhysical1 = (string)myHT[fileId];

    using (

    var fs = new FileStream(pathPhysical1, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 1000, false))
    {

                        string fileName = fileId + ".pdf";
                        FileToSend streamFile = new FileToSend(fileName, fs);

                        await Bot.SendDocumentAsync(tgId, streamFile, "file sended", false);
                        await Bot.SendChatActionAsync(tgId, ChatAction.UploadDocument);

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                capturedException = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
                occuredException = "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException";

            }
            catch (ApiRequestException ex)
            {
                capturedException = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
                occuredException = "ApiRequestException";


            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
            {
                capturedException = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
                occuredException = "TaskCanceledException";


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                occuredException = "Exception";

                capturedException = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);


            }

            if (capturedException != null)
            {

                printExceptionINConsole(capturedException.SourceException, "capturedException-" + occuredException);

                      }
        }
```

thanks in advance
p.s i have post this issue to creator of this api 
https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot/issues/348

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
public static async void sendFileToUser(long tgId, int fileId)
        {
            ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException = null;
            String occuredException = "";
            try
            {
                string pathPhysical1 = (string)myHT[fileId];

                string fileName = fileId + ".pdf";
                var fs = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(pathPhysical1));
                FileToSend streamFile = new FileToSend(fileName, fs);

                await Bot.SendDocumentAsync(tgId, streamFile, "file sended", false);
                await Bot.SendChatActionAsync(tgId, ChatAction.UploadDocument);
            }
            }
            catch (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                capturedException = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
                occuredException = "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException";

            }
            catch (ApiRequestException ex)
            {
                capturedException = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
                occuredException = "ApiRequestException";


            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
            {
                capturedException = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
                occuredException = "TaskCanceledException";


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                occuredException = "Exception";

                capturedException = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);


            }

            if (capturedException != null)
            {

                printExceptionINConsole(capturedException.SourceException, "capturedException-" + occuredException);

                      }
        }
```

i think something is wrong with your stream.